# Two python scripts that are identical yet only one works in airflow while the other does not?

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, airflow

I have two scripts that are identical, the only difference between to the two is the bigquery SELECT * STATEMENT.

I have had both of these python scripts working for over 6 months but after an image update, only one seems to work?

While debugging I have noticed in the logs that I can't see any issues? I have included the log below.

An FYI I have updated to Image version
composer-1.10.4-airflow-1.10.6

```
    *** Reading remote log from gs://europe-west1-product-class--94c0ea69-bucket/logs/Daily_Product_class_3_Reads_v2/Daily_Product_class_3_Reads_v2/2020-06-17T07:18:29.363316+00:00/1.log.
[2020-06-17 07:18:47,079] {taskinstance.py:630} INFO - Dependencies all met for <TaskInstance: Daily_Product_class_3_Reads_v2.Daily_Product_class_3_Reads_v2 2020-06-17T07:18:29.363316+00:00 [queued]>
[2020-06-17 07:18:47,163] {taskinstance.py:630} INFO - Dependencies all met for <TaskInstance: Daily_Product_class_3_Reads_v2.Daily_Product_class_3_Reads_v2 2020-06-17T07:18:29.363316+00:00 [queued]>
[2020-06-17 07:18:47,166] {taskinstance.py:841} INFO -
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
[2020-06-17 07:18:47,166] {taskinstance.py:842} INFO - Starting attempt 1 of 1
[2020-06-17 07:18:47,167] {taskinstance.py:843} INFO -
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
[2020-06-17 07:18:47,234] {taskinstance.py:862} INFO - Executing <Task(PythonOperator): Daily_Product_class_3_Reads_v2> on 2020-06-17T07:18:29.363316+00:00
[2020-06-17 07:18:47,236] {base_task_runner.py:133} INFO - Running: ['airflow', 'run', 'Daily_Product_class_3_Reads_v2', 'Daily_Product_class_3_Reads_v2', '2020-06-17T07:18:29.363316+00:00', '--job_id', '110566', '--pool', 'default_pool', '--raw', '-sd', 'DAGS_FOLDER/ut003_pc3_dag.py', '--cfg_path', '/tmp/tmp3cq2edj4']
```

Comment: Does this DAG finish successfully, or just keep continuously in `Running` phase for the related  `PythonOperator` task?

Comment: The DAG ends in failure but I am unable to certain why via the logs

Comment: If you don't see any log records, then the reason behind might be that Airflow worker Pod was evicted due high cpu/mem utilization. Have you checked Composer workloads/Pods for evictions?